# How To Create SSL For GCP Load Balancer Using NodeJS?

Tags: node.js, ssl, google-cloud-platform, node-forge

Just as a prelude, I already know how to manually create an SSL cert to add to the GCP load balancer. What Im trying to do is use acme-client to create a certificate that I can then push to the GCP load balancer and automatically have people verify their domain (white labeling).

So here is my code:

```
const createEncryptedCert = () => {
    const { generateKeyPairSync, createSign } = require('crypto');

    const { privateKey, publicKey } = generateKeyPairSync('ec', {
        namedCurve: 'prime256v1', // P-256
        publicKeyEncoding: {
            type: 'spki',
            format: 'pem'
        },
        privateKeyEncoding: {
            type: 'pkcs8',
            format: 'pem'
        }
    });

    console.log('Private Key:', privateKey);
    console.log('Public Key:', publicKey);

    const csrSign = createSign('SHA256');
    const csrData = `-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE REQUEST-----
Subject: CN=example.com
-----END CERTIFICATE REQUEST-----`;
    csrSign.update(csrData);
    csrSign.end();

    const csr = csrSign.sign(privateKey).toString();

    console.log('CSR:', csr);

    return {csr, privateKey}
}

async function initiateCertificateProcess(domain) {
    const { privateKey } = createEncryptedCert();

    const client = new acmeClient.Client({
        directoryUrl: acmeClient.directory.letsencrypt.staging,
        accountKey: privateKey.toString(),
    });

    await client.createAccount({ termsOfServiceAgreed: true });

    const [key, csr] = await acmeClient.forge.createCsr({
        commonName: domain,
    });

    const order = await client.createOrder({ identifiers: [{ type: 'dns', value: domain }] });

    const authorizations = await client.getAuthorizations(order);
    const challenge = authorizations[0].challenges.find(ch => ch.type === 'dns-01');
    const dnsRecordValue = await client.getChallengeKeyAuthorization(challenge);
    
    return {
        recordName: `_acme-challenge.${domain}.`,
        recordType: 'TXT',
        recordValue: dnsRecordValue,
        accountKey: privateKey, // Note: This might need adjusting based on intended use.
        order: order,
        accountUrl: client.getAccountUrl(),
        csr: csr.toString(),
        authorizations: authorizations,
        challenge: challenge
    };
}
```

After the user calls this endpoint they then call a second endpoint to let me know that they have finished adding the Acme TXT record to their DNS.

When they do this I then call this endpoint

```
exports.verifyAndCompleteSSLVerification = async (domain, accountKeyPem, orderUrl, accountUrl, csr, authorizations, challenge) => {
    const acmeClient = require('acme-client');

    const client = new acmeClient.Client({
        directoryUrl: acmeClient.directory.letsencrypt.staging,
        accountKey: accountKeyPem,
        accountUrl: accountUrl
    });

    await client.verifyChallenge(authorizations[0], challenge);
    await client.completeChallenge(challenge);

    await client.waitForValidStatus(challenge);

    const order = await client.getOrder(orderUrl);
    await client.finalizeOrder(order, csr);

    await client.waitForValidStatus(order);

    const certificate = await client.getCertificate(order);

    return certificate;
}
```

It seems as though everything creates as I get a private key from the first call and then in the second call the getCertificate method does return a certificate. The problem is that when I try to add these into GCP I get the following message

```
The SSL certificate and key do not match.
```

Bar the obvious, that the key obviously does not match the certificate, can anyone please help if there are any glaring problems with what I am doing? Or maybe even suggest an easier way to do this within the GCP eco system as I do not want to switch to Cloud Flare or some other service.

Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: You provided details on how you are creating the SSL certificate, but no details on the certificate, certificate chain, private key, or how you are setting up the self-managed certificate into Google Cloud. I saw this error before and if IIRC the certificate chain was the problem.